# Running an Activity a certain interval before going to sleep

Tags: android

I am currently working on customizing an Android system and would like that, a few minutes before going to sleep, a given Activity is run, with the same premises as the sleep function (e.g. if the user performs any action, its timer gets reset).

For instance, let's say that we set its timer to 5 minutes and the device is set to go to sleep after 10 minutes. This means that, as long as there is no user input (or wakelocks acquired etc.), after 5 minutes my Activity is started, and after another 5 minutes the device enters sleep mode (think of it similar to a screensaver).

My initial searches have lead me to the PowerManagerService class, where the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF is broadcast, but the general idea of the code there has so far eluded me.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, sorry. You have no way of determining system-wide inactivity up until the `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` broadcast is sent.

Comment: In that case, I have thought about intercepting the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF after 5 minutes, run the Activity and postpone the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF for another 5 minutes. The only problem I see here is making sure that my listener is the first one to receive that Intent. Is that possible ?

Comment: `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` is not an ordered broadcast. Receivers will all get it. You cannot postpone it, and even if you did, the screen would still be off.

Comment: Would creating a broadcast similar to ACTION_SCREEN_OFF be feasible ? (identical in all areas except name, interval and subscribers)

Comment: You are welcome to broadcast whatever you like. Nobody will be paying attention to your broadcasts except you and any third parties you convince to register receivers for it. Now, I just noticed that your opening sentence has "customizing an Android system" in it. If you are creating your own firmware, you are welcome to fork Android and modify it as needed, which could include you somehow finding out about system inactivity. However, that's outside my area of expertise, and historically StackOverflow has mostly helped developers with the SDK more than with firmware changes.

Comment: OK, thank you for your input. In the meantime, I'll try to see how the sleep intent is sent and build something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use Wakelock to delay the sleep.

1. implement a broadcastreceive , filter the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF
2. when receiving the ACTION_SCREEN_OFF , lock the PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK
3. do what you want....
4. when you finish all the job, release Wakelock. then system go to sleep.